# PHP Carry out variable out of closure

Tags: php, function, laravel

I'm building an application using PHP and Laravel. I imported the Excel module from maatwebsite to make it easy to read the contents from Excel files. I'm using the code below to read the Excel.

```
Excel::load(Input::file('excel'), function ($reader) use ($request) {
   $sheets = $reader->get();
   foreach($sheets as $sheet) {
       //do logic
   }
}
```

Now I wonder if it is possible to carry out a variable from the function above. I tried the following, but without any luck;

```
   $results = Excel::load(Input::file('excel'), function ($reader) use ($request) {
      $sheets = $reader->get();
      foreach($sheets as $sheet) {
          $error = 1
      }
      return $error;
   }
```

When I debug the $results it contains a object from the Excel maatwebsite class. Is there any way to carry out the $error variable?

Comment: I don't know Excel, but it seems like you can add results to the `$reader` object, and read from that, since `load()` returns the reader object. It's usually not a good idea to use scoped variables out of scope, even though this will work in PHP because it's not async (yet?).

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own question I fixed it with:

```
$value = "";

Excel::load(Input::file('excel'), function ($reader) use ($request, &$value) {
   $sheets = $reader->get();
   foreach($sheets as $sheet) {
       $value = $error;
   }
}

echo $value;
```

Comment: Another way is to declare $value inside the closure with the `global` keyword like this: `global $value`